# Time series methodology to predict sales

Tags: time-series, modeling

Today I dont want to go deep in the math but mostly be sure I understand the correct methodology.

My goal is to predict sales in 50 different stores. For each store I know the number of products sold by categories (e.g of category: grocery, book, clothes...). I have got additional information like holiday day, weather ...

From my understanding I need to have a 2 steps process.

First, check if additional variables are correlated with sales. For example does weather affect sales, does holiday have an impact...

Then I can start modelisation.

Since I have different stores and different products types, I will need to use a multivariate times series model that will have, as minimum input: store and product type.

In case I have found correlation with other variables, for example weather, I will add this to the model too.

Am I right?

Comment: I have corrected (in particular) all occurrences of "sells" into "sales".

Comment: Do you want to predict *total* store sales, or sales per product? Note that in order to leverage the weather, you will need to forecast the weather itself... and that a lot of the correlation with weather is already captured by seasonality. You may find [this section in the Forecasting Encyclopedia](https://forecasting-encyclopedia.com/practice.html#Retail_sales_forecasting) useful.